# Is it legal to reward points when users click share button?

Tags: facebook

Every website will desire its content to be shared by its users.

Is it OK for some website to award points each time its user clicks facebook share or like button?
assume that the website knows the user's facebook details.

I remember reading somewhere that one must not do this.

If and only if its legal: is there a way to do it - i mean how to capture each time when user clicks on share / like button.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the individual social network's terms and conditions - so you've a lot of reading to do!

IMHO I don't think it will be a problem and there seem to be [plenty of sites and tools](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rewarding%20users%20for%20sharing) that reward users for sharing in one way or another.

Comment: @Christofian I stumbled across this on the web:

This answers the how to part :)

http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2011/12/05/social-currency-giving-back-to-your-customers-for-promoting-your-app/

Comment: also this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/